# django-mysql-manager: CREATE ROLE administrator WITH LOGIN CREATEDB CREATEROLE PASSWORD '1234';

Tags: mysql, django

In installing `django-mysql-manager`:

```
$ source <venv>/bin/activate
(venv)$ pip install django-mysql-manager
$ mysql -u root -p'root'
mysql> CREATE ROLE administrator WITH LOGIN CREATEDB CREATEROLE PASSWORD '1234';
```

I got the error message:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ROLE administrator WITH LOGIN CREATEDB CREATEROLE PASSWORD '1234'' at line 1
```

What went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, that is not a valid command for MySQL.

MySQL does not have any such concept as roles, so that command simply does not exist. Perhaps you were meaning to run it against PostreSQL?

Comment: It's from https://pythonhosted.org/django-mysql-manager/configuration.html#mysql-administrator-role. Is it wrong?

Comment: Well, yes. I have no idea why that line is there. However, since that project appears to be totally unused and unmaintained, and doesn't even seem to have any code, I don't see why you should even be looking in its documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Daniel. Well, I didn't notice that. Actually, I need something like phpmyadmin for Django. Do you have any suggestions?